# Prove that $\sup(f(x)\cdot g(x)) \leq \sup(f(x))\cdot \sup(g(x))$ for nonnegative $f$, $g$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Supremum and Bounded Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116526/the-supremum-and-bounded-functions)
>   [Suprema proof: prove $\sup(f+g) \le \sup f + \sup g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/suprema-proof-prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g)

I am trying to prove this inequality but I don't seem to have any lead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** If you can prove that $f(x)\cdot g(x) \leq \sup(f)\cdot \sup(g)$, for all $x$, what you want will follow because you will have proven that $\sup(f)\cdot \sup(g)$ is an upper bound of $f\cdot g$ and therefore it's greater than the smallest upper bound.

Comment: Did it. Thanks!