# $\sup (A\cdot B)=\sup A \cdot \sup B$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that $\sup (A\cdot B)=\sup A \cdot \sup B$, where $A,B$ are sets of positive real numbers. I've already proved $\sup (A+B)=\sup A +\sup B$ and $\sup (c\cdot A)=c\cdot \sup A$$(c\gt 0)$ easily without any problems. However, I'm stuck in the multiplication $A\cdot B$ case.

I need help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46738/264

Comment: @user42912 [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276266/prove-that-supfx-cdot-gx-leq-supfx-cdot-supgx-for-nonnegativ/276268#276268) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to original question:

If $A=\{-1,+1\}$, and $B=\{-2,1\}$, then $\sup A = 1$, $\sup B = 1$, but $\sup A \cdot B = 2$.

Answer to updated question:

If $A,B \subset [0,\infty)$, then if $a \in A, b \in B$, we have $ab \leq \sup A \sup B$, hence $\sup A \cdot B \leq \sup A \sup B$.

Furthermore, since $\sup A \cdot B = \sup_{a \in A} \sup_{b \in B} ab$, we have $a b \leq \sup A \cdot B $ for all $a \in A, b \in B$. Since $a,b \geq 0$, we have $a \sup B \leq \sup A \cdot B$, and hence $\sup A \sup B \leq \sup A \cdot B$.

Hence they are equal.

Comment: please see my edit, thanks for your answer

Comment: I have added an updated answer.